# Remote ssh script execution with EOI or EOSSH adding dots in front of commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, terminal, remote

Here the first block was running, second block was not. And the problem was EOI considers spaces as dots, I think. But, it does not consider tab as dot. Making no indentation worked for me. But is there any way to specify not to consider tabs or spaces as dots?

```
ssh -tt -vvv -i $pathToPem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $sshUsernameIp << EOI

    sudo rm -rf letsencrypt.tar.gz
    sudo rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/chain.crt

    sed -e 1b -e '$!d' $remote_home_dir/.bashrc
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot -y
    sudo apt-get install certbot -y &
    exit
    trap exit INT

EOI
###############
ssh -tt -vvv -i $pathToPem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $sshUsernameIp << EOI

    sudo certbot certonly -n --agree-tos --register-unsafely-without-email --standalone -d $FQDN
    sudo chown -R root:sudo /etc/letsencrypt/
    sudo chmod -R 750 /etc/letsencrypt/
    sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/local/share/
    sudo cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/$FQDN/chain.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/chain.crt
    sudo update-ca-certificates
    sudo tar -czvf letsencrypt.tar.gz /etc/letsencrypt
    exit

EOI
```

**Updated**
Now, the first part works, when it goes to second part begins at line ############### it says the following:

```
Command '.sudo' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sudo' from deb sudo
  command 'sudo' from deb sudo-ldap

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Someone shared a solution before but later removed it, I think that would work for me. :)

Why is it adding "." in front of all commands?

Comment: Your question seems to have gone through several revisions and changed entirely. The core of your problem still seems to be about here documents, so maybe some [documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) will be useful. The 'tabs turning into dots' problem is discussed here: https://serverfault.com/q/898964/349846

Comment: Thank you very much, those documentations are gems. I copied and pasted  my script from mac (sublime) to linux(vim) instead of using scp. Learnt a good and painful lesson.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked out well. If you could write an answer here with the steps you took to solve the problem, it may be helpful to a future reader. Just something to consider. :-)